# How should I checkout executable files from a Git repository to the runtime environment?

Tags: git, simulink

I do development on a simulink model that is compiled into code to run on hardware. I am the only developer, but I still use git in order to store and track changes to the model. I have traditionally been cloning the entire repository on both my personal computer where I do development and also the runtime computer where the model is used. It has gotten to the point though that the repository is so big that it doesn't really make sense to pull the whole thing to my runtime environment every time when I only need 1 folder from the repository that contains the runnable files. Also, I don't believe this is the proper way to use git anyways, but it is just convenient to only have to hit "pull" to get everything up to date. I also want the ability to clone older versions of that runtime folder. I don't want to have to re-download that folder every time I recompile a model, so what is an easier way of keeping that one runtime folder up to date? I have heard of partial cloning, shallow cloning, sparse checkouts; just not sure what is best/easiest way to handle this. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you actually writing `git clone` each time?

Comment: If you just do `git pull` to sync down, there is no reason for it to pull the whole thing down every time.  It would be easier for us to help you if you could describe your workflow in terms of sequence of commands you typically execute.

Comment: Actually I am using GitHub Desktop for everything, no command-line. But I imagine if I want to do any of the other clone options I will have to use command-line. In Desktop I basically commit changes then push. Then I move over to the runtime computer and do fetch changes then pull. That's basically it. The trouble comes when I want to checkout other versions of the runtime from the history.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I received a similar requirement which I solved by the following commands:

```sh
   git clone --no-checkout --depth=1 {{GIT_REPO_URL}} {{LOCAL_CLONE_PATH}} \
&& cd {{LOCAL_CLONE_PATH}} \
&& git checkout HEAD {{FILENAME_TO_CHECKOUT}}
```

In this way you don't clone the whole repository, but extract only the resource (executable in you scenario) that you need.

Comment: Would this command still work if FILENAME_TO_CHECKOUT was FOLDER_TO_CHECKOUT instead? Would this command work in a batch file so it wouldn't have to be typed out every time?

Comment: Yes , it may works too, but you may should append `/*`. Give it a try.